# List almost in list of lists Python

Tags: python, list, numpy, python-3.6

I have a list of lists in python, where in my case the  lists are coordinates. I want to append new coordinates to this list, but only if the coordinate does not exist yet. This is easily doable in the following manner.

```
List = [coord1,coord2,...,coordn]
coord = [x,y,z]
if not coord in List: List.append(coord)
```

The problem is that these coordinates are generated with all kinds of goniometric functions, so they are floats, and the following minimal example can arise:

```
List =[[0,0],[1,0]]
coords = [0.99999999999,0.000000000001]
```

I do not want to add the new coordinate, so I was wondering if there is some kind of easy way to check if there is a simple function `func`, which would do something like the following:

```
List =[[0,0],[1,0]]
coord = [0.99999999999,0.000000000001]
tol = 1e-10 
func(coord,List,tol) = True
```

i.e. `func` returns `True` if there is a existing coordinate `c` in List, such that `||c-coord||<tol`. One of the constraints is that List remains a list, so it is preferred if it doesn't need to be converted to a numpy array, but the use of numpy in general is possible, and necessary I guess.

Comment: Something something `math.isclose`.

Answer (score 0):

this is a common problem, which can be solved by rounding the float value:

```
coord = [0.99999999999,0.000000000001]
rounded_coord = [ '%.2f' % elem for elem in coord ]
```

this should return the list with the rounded float values, but they will be of type String.
to work with the data, it is probably better to convert the strings to floats again by changing the code:

```
rounded_coord = [ float('%.2f' % elem) for elem in coord ]
```

Comment: Are you sure that `2.995` and `3.005` should be considered as the same value?